# parsing multiple values from a file

Tags: parsing, shell, sed, awk

I have a file that is just one line (one HUGE line) to parse. I want to parse out the value that appears between "Undefined error code" and " id" on this line. The thing is this appears multiple times on the same line with different values everywhere. The following code only gives me the last instance.

```
cat bad_events_P2J3.xml | sed -n 's/.*Undefined error code (\(.*\))\" id.*/\1\n/p'
```

How can I get all instances of this?

Comment: Why not replace "id." with "\n"? Then each record is on a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track:

```
sed -n 's/.*Undefined error code\(.*\)id.*/\1/p' bad_events_P2J3.xml
```

Note that `cat` is unnecessary and, unless you need an extra newline, `sed` will provide one for you.

I missed the fact that this appears multiple times in your file. This should work in that case:

```
grep -Po 'Undefined error code.*?id' bad_events_P2J3.xml | sed 's/^Undefined error code//;s/id$//'
```

Comment: so the cat caused the problem? I thought I should be able to do it with sed. I just wasn't seeing the wood for the trees. Thanks

Comment: @amadain: No, `cat` wasn't the problem. It just wasn't necessary since `sed` accepts a filename as an argument and you're not conCATenating multiple files. The problem was probably the extra set of parentheses. Without seeing a portion of the actual data, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @OP, this works only is you are sure you have 1 instance of those pair of words.It will only get the last instance is there are more because sed is greedy.

Comment: thank you for this. Actually the double parenthesis are needed as the phrase that appears multiple times is actually "Undefined error code(code_here)" id="code_here" so the instance of the number I was matching was in parenthesis. The grep -Po was what I actually needed. The first solution had the same problem as mine i.e. it only displayed one instance - the last instance

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
text1 text2 Undefined error code text3 text4 id text5 text6 Undefined error code txt7 txt8 id
$ awk -vRS="id" '{gsub(/.*Undefined error code/,"")}1' file
 text3 text4
 txt7 txt8
```

Comment: wonderful. I couldn't find how to do this anywhere. It seems like it would be an easy thing that you could do with simple sed but its a lot harder when you tackle it. This code was perfect. Thanks